# Uninstalling maynard desktop on raspbian

Tags: software-installation, maynard

I have done a full install of the new Maynard desktop in development, using this script [here](http://raspberrypi.collabora.co.uk/setup-maynard.sh), and added my user to the group `weston-launch`. Is there any way to completely undo these changes, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Prefer `aptitude` over `apt-get`.

Let's take the script backwards:

```
aptitude remove --purge maynard
```

Comment out (or delete) the last two lines in `/boot/config.txt` which say

```
gpu_mem=128
dispmanx_offline=1
```

Rename `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/collabora-experimental.list` to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/collabora-experimental.list.removed` (only **.list* files are taken into account).

This should undo what the script has done.

Comment: Thanks. What about all the dependencies that it installs as well?

Comment: I also worked out that I need to execute `sudo groupdel weston-launch` as well to remove the group.

Comment: `aptitude` is advertised to take care of the dependencies better than apt-get. It should remove all of them along with maynard.